# Configure Local Git Repo that Updates Two Different Remote Repositories

Tags: git, github, git-remote

I have a local repository that contains public directories and private directories. I push this entire local repository to my internal server.

I want to push only certain directories to my public-ally accessible git server. How do I set this up correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The best practice would be to:

- split your repo in two separate repos

  - see [Atlassian tutorial](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Split+a+repository+in+two)
  - see [GitHub tutorial](https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/)
- push the public one to the public git server.

Trying to keep everything in one repo is dangerous and you would end up mistakenly push what you don't want.

Comment: That would require me to keep two different repo's up to date as I do development. That is equivalent to saying, stop using a version management tool. Not really acceptable.

Comment: @rbell no, you still manage the history of your separate repos.

Comment: I guess I don't understand. Could you elaborate more?

Comment: Each repo still contain the full history of each directory. You would still add and commit, in each repo.

Comment: If I make a change to development code in repo A, I would need to then go to repo B and make the same changes by hand. This is what I'm saying is unacceptable. It requires managing two directories by hand, which is what version control is meant to track. Am I still misunderstanding something?

Comment: @rbell you wouldn't have to, if I assume each folder have a different content, different files for different purpose.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm really having trouble understanding your point. Let me read through your tutorial posts and perhaps it will become clear then.

Comment: @rbell When you say you need to go to repo B and duplicate a change, do you mean both directories have the same files, but with different content? (one content "public", one content "private")?

Comment: No I don't. Public has different content then private does. Both directories are needed when full system testing is occuring. However, when I am working on just part of the system at home, I only need the public files to test. I don't want the private files outside of the internal server.

Comment: What I'm envisioning, is being able to choose what folders I push to my internal git repo and what folders I push to my external public git repo (say github). On my local work computer, everything lives in one directory structure, but I can choose what get's pushed to what remote repo. Everything get's pushed when I update the internal repo, only a subset get's pushed when I update the github repo. Does that make sense?

Comment: @rbell yes. Using two separate repos for that make sense (and you can group them within a third parent repo using submodules: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)